# Javascript timestamp adding 24hrs

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

Using the javascript error console in chrome:

```
new Date()
Sat Apr 19 2014 21:31:35 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)

new Date().getTime()
1397935905577
```

gives me a time stamp of now

it is a little hard to show you because time keeps moving (someone stop it for a sec please)

```
new Date(1397935465774);//a current time
Sat Apr 19 2014 21:24:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)


new Date(1397935471308)//a current time plus 86400
Sat Apr 19 2014 21:24:31 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
```

because 24hrs is made of 86400 seconds, like this:

```
(new Date().getTime())+86400
1397936020170
```

but there is only like ten minutes (ish I can't tell time very well) difference

```
new Date(new Date().getTime())
Sat Apr 19 2014 21:33:40 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)



new Date((new Date().getTime())+86400)
Sat Apr 19 2014 21:31:45 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
```

Why?

Comment: Any chance there a daylight savings time event happening then?

Comment: If 1397936020170  was in fact a UNIX timestamp in seconds, it would represent the year 46267 (1970 + 1397936020170/(60*60*24*365.25)). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer value is in milliseconds, try adding `86400000`.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date().getTime()` gives you time in milliseconds, not seconds!